# Filter on multiple values for single property on Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there a way to filter models in a Backbone collection based on an array of possible property values? I'm looking for a way to express something like the following:

```
var results = myCollection.where({id: [0, 1, 2]});
```

This would return a list of all models with ids matching any listed in the array.

**Update**
The first answer looks good for a single property, but I actually need to do this for multiple properties. So, the example above would look more like this:

```
var results = myCollection.where({id: [0, 1, 2], quality: [0, 2], strength: ['high']});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a complex `filter` statement, but you might want to ask yourself why you want to do this, and why you want to do this especially on the client side.

Have you considered either making this a query to your server, or perhaps restructuring your data in a way that makes this more convenient?

From a very non-optimized and untested standpoint, you could do something like this, where your arguments are the model or collection, followed by an object of `{key: [val1, val]}` pairs.

```
function multiFilter(){
    var filters = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var model = filters.pop();
    return model.filter(function(m){
        var returnModel = false;
        Object.keys(filters).forEach(function(key){
           if(_.has(model[key], filters[key]){
               returnModel = true;
           } else {
               returnModel = false;
           }
        });
        return returnModel;
    });
 }
```

Comment: The dataset is static and small and is contained in a single JSON file. I like the idea of restructuring the data to accommodate faster lookups.

Comment: @jeremynealbrown whenever I find myself trying to compute complex associations out of my data I try to instead look at my data to figure out if I can pre-make them rather than compute them, especially on the client end.

Answer (score 3):

```
var results = myCollection.where(function(model){
    return [0,1,2].some(function(el){
        return model.get('id')===el;
    });
});
```

should work.

or try an extensive aggregation framework: (compatible with Backbone )

https://www.npmjs.org/package/mingo

Comment: This looks great for a single property, but I wasn't clear enough in my description of the problem. I'll need to do this for multiple properties. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Mingo looks interesting.